# Build .apk file on angular by CORDOVA

Tags: angular, cordova

just having a little issue with Cordova and need your help as Im pretty new to it!

So I have created a new Cordova Project on MAC using the Command Prompt. Added the Android platform and followed the path mentioned in the below link
https://medium.com/@Amit_Shukla/deploy-angular-6-0-html-js-css-app-to-ios-and-android-using-apache-cordova-8a3af6bbe3ae
then in **WWW** folder i replaced the folder with build file.which i created by command **ng build --prod** .Then in terminal **cordova run browser** it was fine for me showing my project.But in terminal **cordova build android** the build apk file came .When i installed the apk file its **white screen**.

Is there anything I have missed? Some settings to do? I couldn't find anything from my researches on the Web but clearly something is going wrong.

Thx!!

Comment: check the index.html, try remove `<base href="/">` or use `<base href="./">`

Comment: @Eliseo ya now its works fine but the API request issue is coming. can you just telling me.How to see the error as we in web browser by console in apk app.